# Rails 3 : Anticipating migration for 2.3 beginners

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coding-style, upgrade

I am a beginner in Rails. I use 2.3.X.

I just saw Rails 3 is pre-released [*edit: now in release candidate!*]. I will most probably eventually switch to it.

What are the common coding habits in 2.3 I should not take, so that the switch is as smooth as possible ?

**Edit:**

I've done my homework and read the Release notes. But they are far from clear for the most crucial points, for example :

> 1.5 New APIs
>
> Both the router and query interface have seen significant, breaking changes. There is a backwards compatibility layer that is in place and will be supported until the 3.1 release.

This is not comprehensive enough for a beginner like me. What will break ? What could I do already in 2.3.X to avoid having troubles later ?

Comment: Did you have a look at Jeremy McAnally's posts as I suggested in my answer? I don't think you can get more comprehensive guides to upgrading to Rails 3 these days. Not only he guides you through the whole process, he even wrote a gem to make the transition as painless as possible.

Comment: I understand, Milan, but the topic is not how to migrate, but how to code so that I don't run into too many problems during the migration. I understand the value of your answer and of the link you gave, though. I learned, for example, that I must keep the routing simple. That's already a valuable information. If that's all I need to know, fine. But maybe there are other points.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at my personal coding habits (I have been using Rails since 1.2.x), here's a list of API changes you can anticipate according to [Rails 3 release notes](http://guides.rails.info/3_0_release_notes.html).

**find(:all)**

Avoid the usage of:

```
Model.find(:all)
Model.find(:first)
Model.find(:last)
```

in favour of:

```
Model.all
Model.first
Model.last
```

**Complex queries**

Avoid the composition of complex queries in favor of named scopes.

**Anticipate Arel**

Rails 3 offers a much cleaner approach for dealing with ActiveRecord conditions and options. You can anticipate it creating custom named scopes.

```
class Model
  named_scope :limit, lambda { |value| { :limit => value }}
end

# old way
records = Model.all(:limit => 3)

# new way
records = Model.limit(3).all

# you can also take advantage of lazy evaluation
records = Model.limit(3)
# then in your view
records.each { ... }
```

When upgrading to Rails 3, simply drop the named scope definition.

**Constants**

Avoid the usage of the following constants in favour of the corresponding `Rails.x` methods, already available in Rails 2.x.

- `RAILS_ROOT` in favour of Rails.root,
- `RAILS_ENV` in favour of Rails.env, and
- `RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER` in favour of Rails.logger.

**Unobtrusive Javascript**

Avoid heavy JavaScript helpers in favour of unobtrusive JavaScript.

**Gem dependencies**

Keep your `environment.rb` as clean as possible in order to make easier the migration to Bundler. You can also anticipate the migration [using Bundler today](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/03/using-the-new-gem-bundler-today/) without Rails 3.

Answer (score 3):

The [release notes](http://guides.rails.info/3_0_release_notes.html) are the most important thing to keep an eye on. Other than that Jeremy McAnally has some neat [blog posts](http://omgbloglol.com/) about the whole Rails 3 thing (and has just released a [gem](http://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade) to help you with the migration).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, read the [rails release notes](http://guides.rails.info/3_0_release_notes.html) and see for yourself what seems the more surprising to you. A lot of stuff changed so reading this is definitively very important.